# Set active Bootstrap tab based on React state variable

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am using straight-up Bootstrap 5 (NOT React Bootstrap) in a React app. I need to be able to set the active tab based on a state variable.

My first attempt at this was to use conditinoal JSX to add the `show` and `active` classes directly to the active `tabpanel` items in the component's render code. This did NOT work; it appears that Bootstrap really needs you to fire JavaScript 'click' events on the tabs in order to show/hide the corresponding panels.

My second attempt at this was to use a `useEffect()` hook to fire tab `click` events whenever the corresponding state variable changes--something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById(selectedTab +"-tab").click();
},[selectedTab]);
```

This also did not work: While the `tabpanel` corresponding to the state variable would, indeed, show, *the previously-displayed tab would still appear below* (it needs to be hidden).

Any suggestions on how to get this to work? I suspect that this may be a problem related to the asynchronous nature of the updates.

Note: I suspect that there may be an elegant solution to this if I migrate to `react-bootstrap`, but I would prefer to stick with plain vanilla Bootstrap 5 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use bootstrap javascript. Adding the `show` and `active` classes to the tab pane should work. Don't forget to include the bootstrap CSS. See below example:

`public/index.html`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app"></div>
```

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = () => {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState('home');
  console.log('activeKey: ', activeKey);

  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveKey('profile');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            className={`${activeKey === 'home' ? 'active' : ''} nav-link`}
            type="button"
            onClick={() => setActiveKey('home')}
          >
            Home
          </button>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            className={`${activeKey === 'profile' ? 'active' : ''} nav-link`}
            type="button"
            onClick={() => setActiveKey('profile')}
          >
            Profile
          </button>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            className={`${activeKey === 'contact' ? 'active' : ''} nav-link`}
            type="button"
            onClick={() => setActiveKey('contact')}
          >
            Contact
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div className="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div
          className={`${
            activeKey === 'home' ? 'active show' : ''
          } tab-pane fade`}
        >
          home content
        </div>
        <div
          className={`${
            activeKey === 'profile' ? 'active show' : ''
          } tab-pane fade`}
        >
          profile content
        </div>
        <div
          className={`${
            activeKey === 'contact' ? 'active show' : ''
          } tab-pane fade`}
        >
          contact content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4sx8b4?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question! I viewed your example and it definitely works! My use case is a bit different: the tabbed UI is reacting to a state variable shared across multiple components. I want different components to be able to set the state variable to (programmatically) change the tab that is active. I think your example is working because the user is physically clicking each tab to switch the tab. I do not think your example will work if we programmatically update the state variable without the user clicking the tab to be activated.

Comment: I have confirmed that your approach doesn't work if we programmatically set the `activeKey` state variable in a `useEffect()` after first render. See this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-byk7wr?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: @SpeedGolfer Updated answer. I forgot to set the `active` class on the nav link.